# python prometheus client limit return metric

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus

this is my python code
I want when call enpoint /metric_cpu1
only return metric `nbl_cpu_usage1`
does it's posible ?

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import prometheus_client
from prometheus_client import Counter, Gauge, generate_latest, REGISTRY
import random
from art import text2art
import data_source.cpu as cpu

app = Flask(__name__)

CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST = str('text/plain; charset=utf-8')
prometheus_client.REGISTRY.unregister(prometheus_client.GC_COLLECTOR)
prometheus_client.REGISTRY.unregister(prometheus_client.PLATFORM_COLLECTOR)
prometheus_client.REGISTRY.unregister(prometheus_client.PROCESS_COLLECTOR)

# ====================================
nbl_cpu_usage = Gauge(name='nbl_cpu_usage',
                      documentation='all cpu core average usage',
                      labelnames=['unit']
                      )

nbl_cpu_usage1 = Gauge(name='nbl_cpu_usage1',
                      documentation='all cpu core average usage1',
                      labelnames=['unit']
                      )
# ====================================
# define route

@app.route('/metric_cpu', methods=['GET'])
def metric_cpu():

    nbl_cpu_usage.labels(unit='percent') \
                 .set(cpu.cpu_percent(interval=None))
    
    return Response(generate_latest(), mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)

@app.route('/metric_cpu1', methods=['GET'])
def metric_cpu1():

    nbl_cpu_usage1.labels(unit='percent') \
                 .set(cpu.cpu_percent(interval=None))
    
    return Response(generate_latest(), mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Art=text2art("nbl exporter")
    print(Art)

    app.run(debug=False, port=50000, host='127.0.0.1')
```

here is current ouput
what ever I call endpoint `metric_cpu`, `metric_cpu1`
ther will return both `nbl_cpu_usage`, `nbl_cpu_usage1` metric

```
# HELP nbl_cpu_usage all cpu core average usage
# TYPE nbl_cpu_usage gauge
nbl_cpu_usage{unit="percent"} 5.9
# HELP nbl_cpu_usage1 all cpu core average usage1
# TYPE nbl_cpu_usage1 gauge
nbl_cpu_usage1{unit="percent"} 6.4
```

I wish can be
when call endpoint `metric_cpu`, only return `nbl_cpu_usage` metric

```
# HELP nbl_cpu_usage all cpu core average usage
# TYPE nbl_cpu_usage gauge
nbl_cpu_usage{unit="percent"} 5.9
```

when call endpoint `metric_cpu1`, only return `nbl_cpu_usage1` metric

```
# HELP nbl_cpu_usage1 all cpu core average usage1
# TYPE nbl_cpu_usage1 gauge
nbl_cpu_usage1{unit="percent"} 6.4
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out looking into the doc [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/master/docs/content/restricted-registry/_index.md).

You should change your response from

```
return Response(generate_latest(), mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)
```

to

```
return Response(generate_latest(REGISTRY.restricted_registry(['nbl_cpu_usage1']), mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)
```

Bye!